# Graphics performance reduced

Tags: graphics, performance, ram

I've installed Ubuntu recently. I love gaming on PC and I am trying out Ubuntu. But... I've been having a problem. My graphics card performance had been reduced in this OS. I used to run games in Windows that I cannot in Ubuntu because of this.  Here is all the information about my Graphics Card

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/M92 [**Mobility Radeon HD 4530/4570/545v**] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 0212
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at c0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [**size=256M**]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=256]
    Memory at d6200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Expansion ROM at d6220000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

As you might have seen there... It says my Graphics RAM is 256MB... It says the same in steam. But my graphic memory had always been 512MB... BIOS is there to confirm. But someway, it's saying that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the open-source driver (radeon) instead of the proprietary one (fglrx), which would account for the lack of performance.

Unfortunately, it also looks like you have a Radeon 4500 series graphics card, which ATI/AMD no longer supports with the current version of Xorg. This is probably why the proprietary driver isn't available.

See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/203698/164093. You may be able to install `fglrx-legacy` if you're running 12.10 or lower.

Comment: Oh, I see...
Well, that explains a lot. I tried what you told me. To install fglrx-legacy. But, just when I finish installing it, following all the instructions to install it correctly, it crashes. It says:
 failed to install, because this is not a linux package. Please remove package and try again.

 Yes... I use an ATI Mobility Radeon 4500 series. My version of Ubuntu is 12.04.3 LTS.

 Well. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on [ppa page](https://launchpad.net/~makson96/+archive/fglrx)? If you're running 12.04, you will need to install `linux-image-generic-lts-quantal` and `linux-headers-generic-lts-quantal` before installing `fglrx-legacy`.